# How export from a variable in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I want to export from an address and that address is a string in a variable.

```
 import {device} from 'device.js'

  let buttonUrl;

  if(device.desktop){
    buttonUrl = './components/Elements/Button/Button'
  }
  else if(device.mobile || device.tablet){
    buttonUrl = './components/Elements/Button/ButtonMobile'
  }


  export {
    Button,
  } from buttonUrl
```

I'm getting an error for the export part.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to export `buttonUrl`:

```
export { buttonUrl }
```

And I think this is what you want?

```
import { buttonUrl } from '...'
require(buttonUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Button = require(buttonUrl)
export default Button
```